# Blender Import BVH file and render this skeleton to make video

Tags: python, rendering, blender, blender-2.76, mo-cap

I have a private project to import a custom BVH file (motion capture file) and convert it to an animation video. I tried to do it with Blender and want to do this task with no windows of blender (just execute blender - python script).

I tried to import BVH file with `bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh` and render it. However, there's no object, just background there. How, do I visualize this custom BVH file and render it?

My codes were from https://github.com/DeepMotionEditing/deep-motion-editing/tree/master/blender_rendering

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./')
import bpy

from options import Options
from load_bvh import load_bvh
from scene import make_scene, add_material_for_character, add_rendering_parameters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = Options(sys.argv).parse()

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    print(args.bvh_path)
    #character = load_bvh(args.bvh_path)
    bpy.ops.import_anim.bvh(filepath=args.bvh_path, axis_up='Y', axis_forward='-Z', filter_glob="*.bvh", target='ARMATURE', global_scale=10.0, frame_start=1, use_fps_scale=False, use_cyclic=False, rotate_mode='NATIVE')
    scene = make_scene()
    armature = bpy.context.object
    #add_material_for_character(armature)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    add_rendering_parameters(bpy.context.scene, args, scene[1])

    if args.render:
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, use_viewport=True)
        exit(0)
```

What I want to achieve

[image: Desired Output]

My current status
[image]

Comment: Hello Choi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! While your question appears to belong here, I would recommend posting the code/script that you are using to try to import the BVH file along with screenshots of your error. It's hard for us to offer advice when we don't know what you have done and what the error looks like, and that will make it more obvious to moderators that what you're asking is a coding question, not a software use question.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.